# Como mudar a cor dos checkbox de um MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android, checkbox

Gostaria de saber se tem como mudar as cores desses `CheckBox` que atualmente é verde (cor padrão) para a cor de acentuação do meu *app*.

[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode personalizar através do `style.xml`, o resultado deve ser semelhante a este:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Add this -->

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>

</style>

<!-- Personalize a cor aqui -->

<style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

#### Detalhes

- [Theming ListPreference Dialogs on Android Lollipop](http://news.ebscer.com/2015/06/theming-listpreference-dialogs-on-android-lollipop/)
- [Building custom preferences with preference-v7](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/)

Comment: Ótimas referências! Você me ajudou de uma forma que... Meu deus! Muito obrigado mesmo :D

Comment: @IagoSilva ... opa! Precisar só dar um grito aqui"

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar um selector, dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Salve ele na pasta **res/drawables/** com o nome de **cb_selector.xml**

Depois na hora de declarar o seu checkbox, coloque-o como button, dessa forma:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:text="My CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso direito aos CheckBox, estou usando MultiSelectListPreference